# Why does my palindrome function not work with spaces in C?

Tags: c, palindrome

I wrote a palindrome function, which for those who don't know, means a function that takes in a word/phrase/sentence and returns true if that word/phrase/sentence is the same string reversed.

For some reason, my function works for cases with no spaces only.

`isPalindrome("madam")` returns `true` which is correct.

`isPalindrome("nurses run")` returns `false` which is **not** correct

**Here's the function:**

```
#include <stdbool.h>

bool isPalindrome(char* str){
    char* ptr;
    char* aux; 

    ptr = str; 

    while (*ptr != '\0') { 
        ++ptr;
    } 
    --ptr; 

    for (aux = str; ptr >= aux;) { 
        if (*ptr == *aux) { 
            --ptr; 
            aux++; 
        } 
        else{
            break;
        }  
    } 

    if (aux > ptr){
        return true;
    } 
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Calling/Driver code:**

```
printf("Question 6a: %s\n", isPalindrome("nurses run") ? "true" : "false"); // prints false - not expected
printf("Question 6b: %s\n", isPalindrome("madam") ? "true" : "false"); // prints true as expected
```

Is there any way I can accommodate for space characters in the original string?

Comment: Are you sure `"nurses run"` should be considered a palindrome? That would mean ignoring spaces. If that is the case then ignoring spaces is exactly what your code should do. The `aux` and `ptr` values should be made to skip over spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your for loop, you could skip over spaces. Check first two if statements right after the for loop.

```
#include <stdbool.h>

bool isPalindrome(char* str){
    char* ptr;
    char* aux; 

    ptr = str; 
    while (*ptr != '\0') { 
        ++ptr;
    } 
    --ptr; 

    for (aux = str; ptr >= aux;) { 
        if(*ptr == ' ') {
            --ptr;
            continue;
        }
        if(*aux == ' ') {
            aux++;
            continue;
        }

        if (*ptr == *aux) { 
            --ptr; 
            aux++; 
        } 
        else{
            break;
        }  
    } 

    if (aux > ptr){
        return true;
    } 
    else{
        return false;
    }
}

int main() {
    printf("Question 6a: %s\n", isPalindrome("nurses run") ? "true" : "false"); // prints true - as expected
    printf("Question 6b: %s\n", isPalindrome("madam") ? "true" : "false"); // prints true as expected
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not approaching this another way?

check for your initial string, see the size (without white-space) of your string, divide by two. if odd, special case. if even, run from the start until the middle, and compare [i] to [size-i] in a for loop

For odd, do the same but without touching the exact middle element (which would end up the same)

^as for the "run through", I know you don't want white-space, but you can just create a temporary string without white-space. You know the maximum size of your string, so allocating/assigning is doable.

Answer (score 0):

Your function checks whether two chars are equal and if they are not, you return false. This attitude would be correct if you were working with only alphabetic signs (a-z, A-Z), but if you have a whitespace (or punctuation mark) inside the string, you will finally compare a letter with a whitespace (or punctuation mark), which will immediately make `isPalindrome` return false.

To avoid that problem, you could first get rid of whitespaces (and punctuation marks, etc.) in your input string and make all the letters lowercase (see 2nd example) and compare this one, e.g. `"nurses run"` would be converted to `"nursesrun"`, and `"Was it a car or a cat I saw?"` would become `"wasitacaroracatisaw"`.

If you would not consider the possibility of lower and uppercase letters in the string, `"testset"` would be a palindrome, but `"tEstset"` would not.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, `nurses run` is not a palindrome. Because, If It has space at 7th character, Then It should have space 4th character too.
Anyway, It's not your need, Right?

So, You want to ignore spaces to check whether it's a palindrome. You could use [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62380077/12347371), Or Make another function to remove all the spaces in the string and call it in your palindrome check function at the beginning.